# Elastic Search Percolation with Bounding Box GeoLocation throws NullPointerException in Lucene

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, geolocation, bounding-box

Interesting problem I'm encountering when we moved from Elastic Search 2.1.0 to 2.2.0.

We're using ES's percolate feature currently, and part of the query involves bounding box query.

*Index Mapping snippet:*

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
       "properties": {
       ...
         "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
         },
       ...
    }
  }
}
```

Then, say, we have a query that filters with geo bounding box:

```
... query... 
{
  "geo_bounding_box": {
    "location": {
      "top_left": [151.197033, -33.85610899999999],
      "bottom_right": [151.22295099999994, -33.879704]
    }
  }
}
```

Upon calling the percolation API, it returns the following response:

```
{
  "took": 18,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 4,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 1,
        "index": "indexname_20160217",
        "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "reason": {
          "type": "null_pointer_exception",
          "reason": null
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "total": 0,
  "matches": []
}
```

To a doc with location:

```
"location": {
  "lat": -33.86747690000000,
  "lon": 151.20697759999996
}
```

but **it doesn't happen all the time**, e.g. if I change the coordinates to something different, it returns a result. Some coordinates would throw it, some doesn't. Any ideas why?

The elastic search server stack trace is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.lucene.search.GeoPointTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper$1.getDocIDs(GeoPointTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java:86)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.GeoPointTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper$1.scorer(GeoPointTermQueryConstantScoreWrapper.java:126)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanWeight.java:280)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanWeight.java:280)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanWeight.java:280)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene.exists(Lucene.java:248)
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.QueryCollector$Match.collect(QueryCollector.java:184)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:218)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:169)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:39)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:821)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:535)
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorService.queryBasedPercolating(PercolatorService.java:816)
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorService.access$400(PercolatorService.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorService$5.doPercolate(PercolatorService.java:609)
        ... 10 more
```

Any ideas why this happens to some latlongs would be great. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I been having a similar issue and I believe this is a bug in Elasticsearch 2.2.0 due to all the work that has been done with geo, details here [Supercharging geo_point fields in Elasticsearch 2.2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/supercharging-geopoint)

I have filed a bug report on Github with a link to your posting at [Github Issue #16832](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16832) along with my own examples of the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I saw your post in github as well when I tried to search if there are any latest news on this. Hopefully they address this issue soon.

Comment: Elastic folks have provided a workaround - all details are in the ticket link (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16832)